# Nested DocumentSnapshot onSnapshot doesn't yield results

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying a Firestore document for the contents of its data. One of the fields, `listField`, is an array of `DocumentReference`s to other documents. As such, I have nested snapshots: One for the original document, then a loop for all of the documents referenced in `listField`.

When I try to add all of this into `data`, the list data always returns empty. With some testing, I've found that the `list` is always undefined outside of the inner docSnapshot loop, but is correct *within* that loop.

For what it's worth, I've tested this with the inner loop using `getDoc` as well as with `onSnapshot`, and both yield the same results. Any idea why the list in the inner loop doesn't populate?

```
const [data, setData] = useState<DataType>();
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    var docRef = doc(firestore, "/collection/documentId123");
    onSnapshot(docRef, (docSnapshot) => {
      var list: ListType[] = [];
      docSnapshot.data()?.listField.forEach(async (docRef2: DocumentReference) => {
        const doc2 = await getDoc(docRef2);
        list.push({
          id: docRef2.id,
          field: doc2.get("field"),
        });
        // console.log(list) WORKS HERE!
      });
      // console.log(list) IS UNDEFINED HERE!
      setData({
        title: docSnapshot.data()?.title,
        otherField: docSnapshot.data()?.otherField,
        list: list,
      });
    });
  };
  getData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setData()` might run before all promises are resolved. You can use `Promise.all()` instead of using `async` function in `forEach` loop. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<DataType>({});

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    var docRef = doc(firestore, "/collection/documentId123");

    onSnapshot(docRef, async (docSnapshot) => {
      const snapshots = await Promise.all(docSnapshot.data()?.listField.map(r) => getDoc(r))
      const list = snapshots.map((s) => ({
        id: s.id,
        field: s.get("field")
      }))

      setData({
        title: docSnapshot.data()?.title,
        otherField: docSnapshot.data()?.otherField,
        list: list,
      });
    });
  };

  getData();
}, []);
```